# Can Unicode columns include non-Unicode values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, migration, bcp, unicode

I need to convert Unicode column values from UTF16-LE to UTF-8 to then import into MySQL.

Is it safe to assume columns of `NVARCHAR`, `NTEXT`, `NCHAR`, `BIT`, `INT`, `DECIMAL`, `FLOAT`, and `DATETIME` all *must* be Unicode and therefore *will not* have any characters unable to be converted from UTF-16LE to UTF-8 simply by exporting the values to a .txt file and resaving them with the UTF-8 Encoding prior to importing them to MySQL?

Is it safe to assume any unicode columns in SQL Server will not include any characters incapable of being converted from UTF-16LE to UTF-8 after they've been exported to CSV files?

My import fails, regardless if I re-save the CSV with UTF-8 encoding or not. So, I assume either:

1. SQL Server allows non-unicode character in unicode columns that cannot convert correctly to UTF-8 (which I doubt, hence my question to check my assumption); or
2. It's failing elsewhere in the process - e.g. re-saving the CSV files adds something MySQL doesn't like.

I'm using *bcp* to export the values to a CSV. Then, I resave it with the UTF-8 encoding because MS removed the ability to export directly as UTF-8. Finally, I use MySQL's `LOAD DATA INFILE` to import where it fails.

Comment: What error message do you get? Can you see where in your CSV that it fails?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it safe to assume columns of NVARCHAR, NTEXT, NCHAR, BIT, INT, DECIMAL, FLOAT, and DATETIME all **MUST** be UNICODE...

Only the `XML` and `N`-prefixed types (`NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR`, and `NTEXT` [which has been deprecated since SQL Server 2005 was released so please do not use it]) are Unicode. Those other types you mentioned are not strings and are not stored as strings, hence they are not relevant to this question.

> ... and therefore **WILL NOT** have any characters unable to be converted from UTF-16LE to UTF-8...

This is not exactly a valid question. Unicode characters are Unicode characters regardless of their encoding, whether it is UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE, or UTF-32BE. Now, it is possible for the data itself to contain invalid sequences, such as invalid Surrogate Pairs. But then those aren't valid characters in the UTF-8 or UTF-32 encodings either.

> ... simply by exporting the values to a .txt file and resaving them with the UTF-8 Encoding prior to importing them to MySQL?

Well, you need to be sure to save the initial export file with a Unicode-encoding. So you would use either the `-N` or `-w` options with [BCP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx).

Also, make sure that you are doing more than just changing the Byte Order Mark (BOM) of the file and are actually *converting* the Unicode / UT-16LE characters to UTF-8.